# Adding space between buttons?

Tags: html, css, navigation, rollover

Hi I have a code here that is all perfect except one thing. There is NO space between each button in the code. I've tried margin, but unfortunately its an unordered list so I am a bit confused. What would I add or replace to have space between the two buttons. Help?? :(

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>

<style type="text/css">

    .rollovericons a#terms{
        display: block;
        width:138px;
        height:27px;
        background:  url(http://icpy.webs.com/button/Terms.png) no-repeat;
    }

    .rollovericons a:hover#terms{
        background: url(http://icpy.webs.com/button/Terms0.png) no-repeat;
    }
    .rollovericons a#contact{
        display: block;
        width:138px;
        height:27px;
        background:  url(http://icpy.webs.com/button/contact.png) no-repeat;
    }

    .rollovericons a:hover#contact{
        background: url(http://icpy.webs.com/button/contact0.png) no-repeat;
    }

</style>

<body>

<div class="rollovericons">
    <a href="http://www.twitter.com" id="terms"></a>
    <a href="http://www.twitter.com" id="contact"></a>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Your HTML does not include an unordered list. I don't think you have tried setting a margin or padding.

Comment: Just add the `margin-right` rule to the first button styling, or `margin-left` to the second one.

Comment: Hi George, try use "&nbsp;" between the buttons.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just do:

```
.rollovericons a{
    margin: 10px;
}
```

That will add a margin to every `<a>` item inside the `rollovericons` class.

Answer (score 2):

I added a class called space which will add a space in betwween the buttons.

heres the jsfiddle for you to see: http://jsfiddle.net/mFfAX/

```
.space {margin-bottom:15px}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.rollovericons ul li {
display: inline;
list-style-type: none;
padding-right: 7px;
}

<div class="rollovericons">
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.twitter.com" id="terms"></a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.twitter.com" id="contact"></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```